# Bounding $\mathbb P[A_1,...,A_n]$ where $(A_i)$ are not independent

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

Given events $A_1,...,A_n$. We say that $i\leq n$ "is good" iff $A_i$ occurs and $i$ is bad iff $A_i^c$ occurs. We are given $\delta_1,...\delta_n\in[0,1]$ s.t. $\mathbb P[i \text { is good}]\geq1-\delta_i$. The question: Bound $\mathbb P[\exists i\leq n:i\text{ is good}]$.

---

Attempt:

$$\mathbb P[\exists i\leq n:i\text{ is good}]=1-\mathbb P[\forall i\leq n:i\text{ is bad}]
$$
So it suffices to bound 
$$\mathbb P[\forall i\leq n:i\text{ is bad}]
$$
where we know $$\forall i\leq n: \mathbb P[i\text{ is bad}]\leq \delta_i
$$
I don't know how to proceed because it is not given that $(A_i)$ are independent.

Answer (score 2):

In other words, you want to bound $ P[ \bigcup_i A_i]$.  A standard way of doing this is to use the [Bonferroni inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities), which give both upper and lower bounds to the probability of $\bigcup_i A_i$.  This can be viewed as a version of the *principle of inclusion and exclusion*.

Among them, the simplest lower and upper bounds are $$
\sum_{i}P[A_i] - \sum_{i<j} P[A_i\cap A_j]\le P[ \bigcup_i A_i] \le \sum_i P[A_i].$$

How useful this is in practice depends a lot on the particulars of the situation.  The upper bound displayed here (often called the *union bound* or *Boole's inequality*) is often very effective if the individual $A_i$ have small probabilities.